# Is there any way to make an style for all buttons in tkinter?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, styles

I want to make an style for all buttons on my app but I don't know how to do it. I can't find a good tutorial for making themes on tkinter.

I found [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/GUI-Tk/ButtonBorderstyles.htm) but it only changes buttons one by one and I want one same style for all buttons.

Appreciate help

Comment: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html, or create a subclass of `Button` where you can hard-code any attributes that you want.

Comment: problem: I created new theme based on theme "clam" and I applied to ttk then I can't change all buttons. My code:

`style = ttk.Style()
    style.theme_create("MyStyle", parent="clam", settings={
        "TNotebook": {"configure": {"tabmargins": [2, 5, 2, 0]}},
        "TNotebook.Tab": {"configure": {"padding": [10, 10]}, }})
    style.theme_use("MyStyle")`